# Weighted Activity Selection Problem with allowing shifting starting time

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have some activities with weights, and I would like to select non overlapping activities by maximizing the total weight. This is known problem and solution exists.

In my case, I am allowed to shift the start time of activities in some extend while duration remains same. This will give me some flexibility and I might increase my utilization.

Example scenario is something like the following where all activities are supposed to be in interval (0-200):

```
(start, end, profit)
a1: 10 12 120
a2: 10 13 100
a3: 14 18 150
a4: 14 20 100
a5: 120 125 100
a6: 120 140 150
a7: 126 130 100
```

Without shifting flexibility, I would choose *(a1, a3, a6)* and that is it. On the other hand I have *shifting flexibility* to the left/right by *at most* *t* units for any task where *t* is given. In that case I might come up with this schedule and all tasks can be selected except a7 since conflict cannot be avoided by shift .

```
t: 5

a1: 8 10 120 (shifted -2 to left)
a2: 10 13 100
a3: 14 18 150
a4: 18 24 100 (shifted +4 to right)
a5: 115 120 100 (shifted -5 to left)
a6: 120 140 150
```

In my problem, total time I have is very big with respect to activity duration. While activities are like 10sec on average, total time I have would even be 10000sec. However that does not mean all of activities can be selected since shifting flexibility would not be enough for some activities to non-overlap.

Also in my problem, there are clusters of activities which overlaps and very big empty space where no activities and there comes another cluster of overlapping activities i.e *a1, a2, a3 and a4* are let say cluster1 and *a5, a6 and a7* is cluster2. Each cluster can be expanded in time by shifting some of them to left and right. By doing that, I can select more activities than the original activity selection problem. However, I do not know how to decide which tasks to be shifted to left or right.

My expectation is to find an near-optimal solution where total profit would be somehow local optima. I do not need global optimum value.  Also I do not have any criteria about cluster utilization., i.e I do not have a guarantee about a minimum number of activity per cluster etc. Actually, these clusters something I visually describe. There is not defined cluster. However, in time domain, activities are separated as clusters somehow.

Also activity start and end times are all integers since I can dismiss fractions. I would have around 50 activities whose duration would be 10 on average. And time window is like 10000.

Are there any feasible solution to this problem?

Comment: Could it be feasible to code the "shift" as discrete, additional options? For example, given 2 hr flexibility, instead of the flexible task that starts at 6 and ends at 7, our list of selections would now include, (4,5), (5,6), (7,8), (8,9) *and* (6,7)? (We'd have to then guarantee at most one of each such set gets selected. Seems like constraint satisfaction.)

Comment: In my case, my activities are like 5 seconds long and my flexibility is like 2 minute. So it is not possible for each included task to overlap. In that case, I am facing another issue; how to chose at most one task from of non overlapping group. Thats another problem also

Comment: Not sure I understand. A minimal example in the body of the question could help, as well as the kind of data (as you suggested, the kinds of ranges we are looking at).

Comment: @SamiŞimşekli I'm a bit confused with "In my problem, I have more than enough room for each activity in the time domain." - are you saying that you can guarantee that it's possible to select all activities if you shift them optimally? Your example manages to pick all activities, so it doesn't clear up with confusion.

Comment: Separately, do you have some expectation/guarantee on the maximum number activities within each cluster?

Comment: And a third question - are the start/end times always integers (in seconds), or you could literally have a task starting, for instance, at 2:52.2421 and ending at 2:54.352385?

Comment: How big are the interval / allowed shift / number of activities?

Comment: I have edited my question for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you can partition the activities into clusters that don't overlap even if activities within them are shifted to the extent. Each of these clusters can be considered independently, and the optimal results computed for each cluster simply summed up for the final answer. So the first step of the algorithm could be a trial run that extends all activities in both directions, finds which ones form clusters, and process each cluster independently. In the worst case, all of the activities might form a single cluster.

Depending on the maximum size of the remaining clusters, there are several approaches. If it's under 20 (or even 30, depending on whether you want your program to run in seconds or minutes), you could combine search over all subsets of activities in the given cluster with a greedy approach. In other words: if you are processing a subset of N elements, try every one of its `2^N` possible subsets (okay, `2^N-1` if we forget the empty subset), check whether the activities in this specific subset can be scheduled in non-overlapping manner, and pick the subset that is eligible and has maximum sum.

How do we check that a given subset of activities can be scheduled in non-overlapping manner? Let's sort them in ascending order of their end and process them from left to right. For every activity, we try to schedule it as early as possible, making sure it does no intersect with activities we already considered. So, the first activity in the cluster is always started time `t` earlier than originally planned, the second one is started either when the first one ends, or `t` earlier than originally planned, whichever is larger, and so on. If at any point we can't schedule the next activity in a way that it does not overlap with previous one, then there is no way to schedule the activities in this subset in a non-overlapping manner. This algorithm takes `O(NlogN) time`, and overall each cluster is processed in `O(2^N * NlogN)`. Once again, note that this function grows very quickly, so if you are dealing with large enough clusters, this approach goes out the window.

===

Another approach is specific to the additional restrictions you provided. If the activities' starts and ends and parameter `t` are all measured in integer number of seconds, and `t` is about 2 minutes, then the problem for each cluster is set in a small discrete space. Even though you could position a task to start at a non-integer second value, there always is an optimal solution that uses only integers. (To prove it, consider an optimal solution that does not use integers - since `t` is integer, you can always shift tasks, starting from the leftmost, to the left a bit so that it starts at an integer value.)

Knowing that the start and end times are discrete, you can build a DP solution: process the activities in the ascending order of their end*, and memoize the maximum possible sum of weights you can obtain from the first 1, 2, ..., N activities for each `x` from `activity_start - t` to `activity_start + t` if a given activity ends at time `x`. If we denote this memoized function as `f[activity][end_time]`, then the recurrence relation is `f[a][e] = weight[a] + max(f[i][j] over all i < a, j <= e - (end[a] - start[a])`, which roughly translates to "if activity `a` ended at time `e`, the previous activity must have ended at or before start of `a` - so let's pick the maximum total weight over previous activities and their ends, and add the current activity's weight".

*Again, we can prove that there is at least one optimal answer where this ordering is preserved, even though there might be other optimal answers which do not possess this property

We could go further and eliminate the iteration over previous activities, instead encoding this information in `f`. Its definition would then change to "`f[a][e]` is the maximum possible total weight of the first `a` activities if none of them ends after `e`", and recurrence relation would become `f[a][e] = max(f[a-1][e], weight[a] + max(f[a-1][i] over i <= e - (end[a] - start[a])]))`, and its computational complexity would be `O(X * N)`, where `X` is the total span of the discrete space where task starts/ends are placed.

I assume you need to compute not just the maximum possible weight, but also the activities you need to select to obtain it, and possibly even the exact time each of them needs to be started. Thankfully, we can derive all of this from the values of `f`, or compute it at the same time as we compute `f`. The latter is easier to reason about, so let's introduce a second function `g[activity][end]`. `g[activity][end]` returns a pair `(last_activity, last_activity_end)`, essentially pointing us to the exact activity and its timing that the optimal weight in `f[activity][end]` uses.

Let's go through the example you provided to illustrate how this works:

```
(start, end, profit)
a1: 10 12 120
a2: 10 13 100
a3: 14 18 150
a4: 14 20 100
a5: 120 125 100
a6: 120 140 150
a7: 126 130 100
```

1. We order the activities by their end time, thereby swapping a7 and a6.
2. We initialize the values of `f` and `g` for the first activity:

`f[1][7] = 120, f[1][8] = 120, ..., f[1][17] = 120`, meaning that the first activity could end anywhere from 7 to 17, and costs 120. `f[1][i]` for all other `i` should be set to 0.

`g[1][7] = (1, 7), g[1][8] = (1, 8), ..., g[1][17] = (1, 17)`, meaning that the last activity that was included in `f[1][i]` values was `a1`, and it ended at `i`. `g[1][i]` for all `i` outside `[7, 17]` is undefined/irrelevant.

3. That's where something interesting begins. For each `i` such that `a2` cannot end at time `i`, let's assign `f[2][i] = f[1][i], g[2][i] = g[1][i]`, which essentially means that we wouldn't be using activity `a2` in those answers. For all other `i`, namely, in `[8..18]` interval, we have:

`f[2][8] = max(f[1][8], 100 + max(f[1][0..5])) = f[1][8]`

`f[2][9] = max(f[1][9], 100 + max(f[1][0..6])) = f[1][9]`

`f[2][10] = max(f[1][10], 100 + max(f[1][0..7]))`. This is the first time when the second clause is not just plain 100, as `f[1][7]>0`. It is, in fact, `100+f[1][7]=220`, meaning that we can take activity `a2`, shift it in a way that puts its end at time `10`, and get a total weight of `220`. We continue computing `f[2][i]` this way for all `i <= 18`.

The values of `g` are: `g[2][8]=g[1][8]=(1, 8)`, `g[2][9]=g[1][9]=(1, 9)`, `g[2][10]=(2, 10)`, because it was optimal to take activity `a2` and end it at time `10` in this case.

I hope the pattern of how this continues is visible - we compute all the values of `f` and `g` through the end, and then pick the maximum `f[N][e]` over all possible end times `e` of the last activity. Armed with the auxiliary function `g`, we can traverse the values backwards to figure out the exact activities and times. Namely,  the last activity we use and its timing is in `g[N][e]`. Let's call them `A` and `T`. We know that A began at `T-(end[A]-start[A])`. Then, the previous activity must have ended at that point or before - so let's look at `g[A-1][T-(end[A]-start[A])` for it, and so on.

Note that this approach works even if you don't partition anything into clusters, but with the partitioning, the size of the space in which tasks can be scheduled is reduced, and with it the runtime.

You might notice that neither of these solutions is polynomial in the size of input. I have a feeling that your problem doesn't have a general polynomial solution, but I was unable to prove it by reducing another NP-complete problem to it. Would be really curious to read a reduction / better general solution!

Comment: I am now trying to understand the algorithm. In this part I did not get why we get max of *f[1][0..5]* in here: "*f[2][8] = max(f[1][8], 100 + max(f[1][0..5])) = f[1][8*]" . I mean why from 0 to 5 and in the next line why 0 to 6 and so on?

Comment: And another question, is this *f[1][i]* a typo? "... was included in *f[1][i]* values was a1". I suppose it would be g[i][i]. Right?

Comment: For the first question - we are unwrapping the formula `f[a][e] = max(f[a-1][e], weight[a] + max(f[a-1][i] over i <= e - (end[a] - start[a])]))`, and the range of `i` increases with `e`. Essentially we are saying "if my current activity ended at time `e`, then the previous activity must have ended before the current one started, i.e., `e-(end[a]-start[a])`".

Comment: For the second question, I guess confusion comes from lack of precise mathematic notation behind `f` and `g`. What I meant is that `f[1][i]` keeps the sum of weights of some set of activities that is optimal, and `g[1][i]` corresponds to the latest activity from that set.

Comment: Hopefully last question; while traversing backward through `g` function, `g[A-1][T-duration(A)]` might be undefined/irrelevant. In this case, is it correct to chose `g[A-1][j]` where `f[A-1][j]` is the maximum among `f[A-1][0..T-duration(A)]`?

Comment: Instead returning a pair in `g[i][j]` I have returned a list of pairs which kept track of the previous choices. When I pick the max `f[N][e]` over each `e`, `g[N][e]` gives the full list of activities. Back tracking was not needed in this g function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `g[A-1][T-duration(A)]` should have always been defined and relevant by construction, but indeed simplifying it from "store last activity" to "store all activities" makes it much easier to understand. The only issue is that your algorithm becomes slower because it has to overwrite `O(N)` values instead of 1 value when it updates `g` - so if you need to speed it up you could still revert to the recursive definition.

I'd be curious to hear if this turned out helpful in practice!